# Why does getPackageManager return null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, accessibilityservice

So I am trying to start another app my inside my `AccessibilityService` but I keep getting the following `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference` even though I use the same method in my `MainActivity.class` and it works fine. And I know the package name is correct, cause like I said I call it in `MainActivity.class`

This is the class where I call the function.

```
public class myAdapter extends Application
{
   private void turnOn(String text)
   {
       Intent b = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(text);
       startActivity(b);
   }
}
```

I have tried the various ways to call this same function.

```
Intent b = getApplicationContext().getgetPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appName);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(b);

  Intent b = getApplicationContext().getgetPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appName);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(b);
```

My Logcat:

```
Process: com.tech.myApp, PID: 17195
                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:106)
                                                                           at com.tech.myApp.turnOn(myAdapter.java:198)
```

Comment: Because you made an instance of a service by yourself. `The lifecycle of an accessibility service is managed exclusively by the system and follows the established service life cycle` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html). You should not create one with `new` that will leave the rest uninitialized

Comment: Why don't you just call that function in `myAdapter`. It extends from `Application` (although I do not know why from your class name) so you can call that function there too

Comment: If I don't use `private static AutoService AS = new AutoService();` then I can't even call the function without making it static, and if I make it static I can't use intents.

Comment: Okay, but why don't you just move the code from `openApp` to `turnOn`? There is nothing going on in that service that is not achievable in your other class

Comment: Doesn't matter where I move it, still shows up with the exact same error. I have been trying for the last 2 hours to move it to any class except my `MainActivity.class` and it gives the same error.

Comment: Where do you call `turnOn`? Please tell me you don't make an instance of `myAdapter` with `new myAdapter`...

Comment: I turn it on from `public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)`

Comment: Okay. And how did you get an instance of `myAdapter`? Did you instantiate it with `new myAdapter` somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151405/discussion-between-jayce-and-0xdeadc0de).

Answer (score 0):

You say that you're trying to start an `Activity` from an `AccessibilityService`, yet your code very clearly shows that your class is extending `Application`. This is confusing and also likely one of the core issues you're having regarding these `NullPointerExceptions`. I am going to state my answer assuming that you are indeed attempting this from an `AccessibilityService` class, as mentioned in the description of your issue, even though this very much conflicts with the code you have posted. If this is indeed the case, you should update this question to clarify. If this answer does not help you, your question needs considerable TLC.

Once we realize that we're within an `AccessibilityService`, we see that there is a MUCH simpler way to accomplish starting an activity. Starting another `Activity` within an `AccessibilityService` is as simple as the following code snippet:

```
public class A11yService extends AccessibilityService {

    void startMainActivityFromService() {

        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Easy as that!

Comment: I did get it to work, the whole point of why it was NullPointerException is cause there was no context being passed to it. So I will post what I did in a few.

Answer (score -1):

Okay so what I had to do was on my `MainActivity.class` was create a static context. Which then I could pull from any other class even the ones that run in the background.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext();

    // CALL MY FUCTION - THIS COULD BE ANYWHERE NOW
    startApp(app name you want to start);
}
}
```

Then in my other classes or activities or services I use this:

```
public static void startApp(String appName)
{
   // MAKE SURE TO GET THE CONTEXT
   Context context = MainActivity.getAppContext();

   Intent b = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appName);
    context.startActivity(b);
}
```

Comment: Why is context a global?  Why not pass it as an argument?

Comment: @ChrisCM cause where I send the request from doesn't have a context either, it is all done in the background.

Comment: Then pass it around to those background processes and store it as a member variable.

Comment: @ChrisCM is there a better benefit from that rather than using it as a global?

Comment: A: this is terrible style. B: You're depending on things you don't realize you're depending on. Namely that MainActivity has been instantiated, initialized, active, and valid. These guarantees can only be maintained while your Activity is active. If your activity is active, then you can solve this in a better way. If your Activity is not active, you should not be relying on its presence and validity as a Context object. The benefit of other methods is that they don't have these issues.

Comment: Well after `MainActivity` there is nothing else that runs except for background process, my app does not use any UI or "Active" classes, it is all services. So now sure how you would keep passing around a context.

Comment: If you don't have a context to pass around, you don't have a context to access globally. Also, services are a context from which you can launch activities as I demonstrated in my solution.